# Different balun configurations

Tags: rf, surface-mount, balun

I am looking for a balun to be used as a single-ended to differential converter, 1:2 impedance ratio, including range 1.5-2.5GHz, SMT and phase balance as good as possible (and return loss). Center tap (for common mode) would be nice but not required.

When I look at the Mini-Circuits site, I find the following options (which I do *not* see with other vendors like Macom or Coilcraft):

[image]

I know that the following would not work for the setup above:

- D and Q (because it is unbalanced-unbalanced)
- E (seems to be differential-to-single-ended (and not other way))

But for the rest: Is there any reason any of the others would not work as a single-ended-to-differential converter? Particularly, is there any reason why config K or N would not work?

Why does Mini-Circuits provide these different kinds of configuration but other vendors not?

Comment: Mini-Circuits' [app note](https://www.minicircuits.com/app/AN20-002.pdf) on transformers might be helpful.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Unfortunately it does not contain all the architectures. M,N,P,P1,Q,R are not explained. Particularly I can only find a balun of config **N** with acceptable phase balance.

Comment: Why don't you use a transformer instead of a current balun?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that but frequency range up to 2.5 GHz. Transformers don't go that high (need transmission line balun). I was looking at Digikey, Macom, Mini-Circuits and did not find any "good" solutions.